# Haskell Type error with where

Tags: haskell, types

```
type NI = Int
type Age = Int
type Balance = Int
type Person = (NI, Age, Balance) 
type Bank = [Person]


sumAllAccounts :: NI -> Bank -> Int
sumAllAccounts n l = filter niMatch l
    where niMatch n (a,_,_) 
        | n == a    =   True
        | otherwise =   False
```

When I run this function i get a type error

```
couldnt match type (Person, t0, t1) -> Bool with Bool
```

However when I make the where its own function it works

```
personNIMatchs :: NI -> Person -> Bool
personNIMatchs n (a,_,_) 
    | n == a    =   True
    | otherwise =   False
```

Comment: Please include the definition of `Bank`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at the type of `filter`

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a]-> [a]
```

The type of `niMatch` is `NI -> Person -> Bool`

So Haskell unifies `a` with `NI`, but `Person -> Bool` doesn't work! That's not a `Bool`, hence your somewhat confusing error message. To see this visually Haskell is unifying

```
   a   -> Bool
-- ^      ^ unification error!
   NI  -> (Person -> Bool)
```

Now I assume that `type Bank = [Person]` then you just want

```
 sumAllAccounts n = sum . map getBalance . filter matchNI
   where matchNI (a, _, _) = a == n
         getBalance (_, _, b) = b
 -- I've added the code here to actually sum the balances here
 -- without it, you're returning a Bank of all a persons accounts.
```

But we can make this better! Let's do the more idiomatic Haskell approach and store `Person` as a record.

```
newtype Person = Person {
  ni :: NI,
  age :: Age,
  balance :: Balance
} deriving (Eq, Show)

sumAllAccounts :: NI -> Bank -> Balance
sumAllAccounts n = sum . map balance . filter ((==n) . ni)
```

Much neater, now we can use the autogenerated getters.